# Pulling data with specific parameters from db using PHP

Tags: php, class, parameters

Let's say I have 3 columns/divs/sections in my html layout, let's call them cat1, cat2, cat3. Then I have a database with a table called "Content". In that table I have the fields id, title, content, category.

Now I want to populate those 3 columns with their corresponding content from my mysql table. For example - get all the content from table where category = cat1(corresponding to the first column).

I could just make 3 functions that each have their own parameter, but I don't want to repeat code. How can I do this with a single function, but just using a different parameter?

I was thinking something like this:

```
public function displayAll_with_category ($category) {
  $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Category=?");
  $sql->bindParam(1, $category);
  $sql->execute();
  while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    echo $row['Title'];
  }
}
```

Then in my HTML:

```
<div id="cat1">
  // Using a central class
  <?php include('class.php'); $obj = new handler; $obj->displayAll_with_category(); ?>
</div>
```

So far so good, I need to somehow be able to alter the $category parameter so I can use the same function to call the contents for cat1/2/3. I have no idea how to do that, usually I need to send something to the PHP function via a button or form, but this time that's not the case. Is this even doable in pure PHP? I can think of doing this with AJAX, but for now I want to know if it can be done with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

This would get you the data for category 1, 2 and 3.
I just created a loop in the view to call the function with different parameters:

```
<?php
for($cont = 0; $cont<4; $cont++){
?>
<div id="cat1">
  // Using a central class
  <?php include('class.php'); $obj = new handler; $obj->displayAll_with_category($cont); ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Oh and if I were you i would try to separate the logic from the view and I will print the result of the function in the view instead of doing it inside it.